# How to choose between different styles in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, styles

I am creating a popup dialog using microsoft's WPF.

The thing is that this popup must support two or more different styles, for instance, depending on how it is called the popup must have a red background and white text in the foreground, or it must have a white background and gray text in the foreground.

What I would like to do is create as many styles as necessary in my xaml file and just choose each of them depending on how the popup was created, therefore I would like to know if it is possible to create something like this (kind of a dynamically applied style) inside the .xaml file, or if it is better to just do this programatically in the code behind.

Also please note that I am using the Visual Studio 2010 with the .NET Framework 4.0.

Thanks,

Felipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define an enumeration that names the styles, then either use DataTriggers to set the style on the control from a wrapping border.

Comment: Oh, oops, that "either" was meant to point to the given suggestion or, alternative, a custom markupextension, but that seems to have slipped my mind when I posted. Sorry about that.